# A way to hide and unhide a button without grid? (python tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was wondering if there was a way to hide and unhide a button in python without using grid. I've tried moving them to an off-screen location then back once it's triggered by a variable, but that doesn't work (this made the buttons seem like they never existed). Packing, forgetting, then unpacking only seems to work with labels. Let me know if anyone has another way (Note:I am a novice). Here's my code as of now:

```
from tkinter import*
health=1
stamina=1
magica=1
healthcap=1
staminacap=1
magicacap=1
slide=1

def next1(event=None):
    global slide
    if slide==1:
        bglabel.config(image=bg1)
    elif slide==2:
        classstart.pack()
        classstart.pack_forget()
        bglabel.config(image=bg2)
    elif slide==3:
        classstart.pack()
        bglabel.pack()
        bglabel.pack_forget()
        nextbutton1.pack()
        nextbutton1.pack_forget()
    slide+=1
    window.update()

def class_select_screen():
    global slide
    if slide==3:
        classstart.config(image=classdesc)
        rougeselbut.pack()
        mageselbut.pack()
        warriorselbut.pack()
    elif slide<3:
        rougeselbut.pack()
        rougeselbut.pack_forget()
        mageselbut.pack()
        mageselbut.pack_forget()
        warriorselbut.pack()
        warriorselbut.pack_forget()

window = Tk()
window.geometry("1500x750+0+0")

classdesc=PhotoImage(file="classdescription.png")
rougedesc=PhotoImage(file="rougedescription.png")
warriordesc=PhotoImage(file="warriordescription.png")
magedesc=PhotoImage(file="magedescription.png")
bg1=PhotoImage(file="backslide1.png")
bg2=PhotoImage(file="backslide2.png")
nextbutton=PhotoImage(file="next.png")
magesel=PhotoImage(file= "mageselect.png")
warriorsel=PhotoImage(file="warriorselect.png")
rougesel=PhotoImage(file="rougeselect.png")

classlabel=Label(window)
classstart= Label(window, image=classdesc)
classstart.place(x=600, y=200)
bglabel= Label(window, image=bg1)
bglabel.place(x=600,y=200)

rougeselbut= Button(window, image=rougesel, bd=0, command=rouge_select())
rougeselbut.place(x=500, y=200)

warriorselbut= Button(window, image=warriorsel, bd=0, command= warrior_select())
warriorselbut.place(x=670, y=195)

mageselbut= Button(window, image=magesel, bd=0, command=mage_select())
mageselbut.place(x=840, y=200)

nextbutton1=Button(window, image=nextbutton, bd=0, command=next1)
nextbutton1.place(x=100, y=100)

window.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: next1(event))
window.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: rouge_select(event))
window.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: warrior_select(event))
window.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: mage_select(event))
window.mainloop()
```

1. The buttons mageselbut, warriorselbut, and rougeselbut dont do much of anything yet, but they are supposed to be invisible until slide=3, which of course it isn't, leaving class_select_screen pretty useless right now (Is there a way to fix that maybe?).

The classstart label was able to be brought back up fine and I was wondering why. At first I thought that maybe it was just because it wasn't within next1, but I tried this a couple different ways, one where it failed completely just like the others, and another where it was invisible while slide=2, but not 1.

2. Next needs to be clicked twice to get slide to equal 2, which I don't really understand. It starts as 1 and it says slide+=1 at the end so it should go to being slide=2 in one click right?

So yeah. That's a lot there but if anyone has ideas please let me know. I want to stay away from using gridding right now because I'm still not really familiar with it and none of the explanations I've read make sense so I was going to ask my professor about it on Monday. (Though if someone would explain it here that would be awesome, though I know I'm asking a lot)

Sorry if I wasn't clear but thank you in advance.

Comment: FWIW, I find grid a lot easier to use, as it's literally a grid structure with rows and columns. You can then use methods like `grid_forget`. Also, may I ask why you're making an RPG? Was it your idea or your professors? Over the years, I've learned that RPGs are one of the worst ways for a beginner program to learn, as you end up doing a lot of typing and very little programming. (Also, you spelled "rogue" wrong.)

Comment: "Packing, forgetting, then unpacking" doesn't work with just labels.It works equally with all widgets.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yeah we're supposed to be making a short game using the gui interface. Thanks for calling out the typo

Comment: I would highly recommend a different style of game, like a puzzle game. Hangman, Tic-Tac-Toe, Rock Paper Scissors, Mastermind, etc. are smaller and easier to manage, and they'll teach you more about programming.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yeah making an RPG does sound a bit overwhelming at this point, considering I'm barely finished with the intro after a week of all my spare time. I'll keep those options in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide button `b1` displayed by [pack manager](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm), use [`b1.pack_forget()`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm#Tkinter.Pack.pack_forget-method). To display it again, you can do it the same way as if it was never displayed before: using `b1.pack()`, `b1.place()` or (if nothing else is packed already on screen) `b1.grid()`.

Notice that `b1` will be packed at the bottom (after all other already packed widgets). To avoid that, I suggest using different layout manager ([grid](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) or [place](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm)) or, when you want to show `b1` again, hide all the widgets that should be below `b1` and then pack `b1` and them in right order.

I wasn't able to run your code properly because of missing functions, so I can't tell if something is wrong there and debug it for you.

Since you're novice, I'd like to suggest you two tkinter reference sites to find answers to your questions more easily and to expand your knowledge of tkinter:
 [effbot.org](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm) & [infohost.nmt.edu](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html)

There you can find out how gridding works in detail. In short, grid has rows and columns. When being gridded, each widget is placed in its own cell (i-th row, j-th column). By default, each row/column is as tall/wide as the tallest/widest widget inside. That means, if there aren't any widgets in certain row/column, that row/column is not displayed. Of course, you can tweak that with grid options (e.g. row_configure() might help there) For further info check out the sites I linked.